Content Security Policy reports an error, despite blocked-uri being in the original-policy
We added the Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only to our site, and are now examining the reports that got sent back to us. We got this interesting one on a facebook tracking pixel.
{
    "csp-report": {
        "document-uri": "https://app.goreact.com/dashboard/sessions/33788610",
        "referrer": "",
        "violated-directive": "img-src",
        "effective-directive": "img-src",
        "original-policy": "default-src 'self' \t   https://*.goreact.com \t   https://*.goreact.com:* \t   https://*.goreact.eu; \tscript-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' \t   blob: \t   https://*.googletagmanager.com \t   https://*.google-analytics.com \t   https://*.goreact.com \t   https://*.goreact.com:* \t   https://*.goreact.eu \t   https://*.youtube.com \t   https://assets.zendesk.com \t   https://cdn.bizible.com \t   https://cdn.jsdelivr.net \t   https://connect.facebook.net \t   https://edge.fullstory.com \t   https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net \t   https://js.hs-analytics.net \t   https://js.hs-banner.com \t   https://js.hs-scripts.com \t   https://js.hsleadflows.net \t   https://js.hsadspixel.net \t   https://js.intercomcdn.com \t   https://snap.licdn.com \t   https://static.ads-twitter.com \t   https://static.zdassets.com \t   https://widget.intercom.io; \tstyle-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' \t   https://*.goreact.com \t   https://*.goreact.com:* \t   https://*.goreact.eu \t   https://cdn.jsdelivr.net \t   https://fonts.googleapis.com; \timg-src 'self' \t   https://*.analytics.google.com \t   https://*.googletagmanager.com \t   https://*.google-analytics.com \t   https://*.goreact.com \t   https://*.goreact.com:* \t   https://*.goreact.eu \t   https://*.youtube.com \t   https://analytics.twitter.com \t   https://bam.nr-data.net \t   https://cdn.bizible.com \t   https://px.ads.linkedin.com \t   https://t.co \t   https://track.hubspot.com \t   https://www.facebook.com \t   https://www.google.com \t   https://www.linkedin.com; \tfont-src 'self' \t   https://*.goreact.com \t   https://*.goreact.com:* \t   https://*.goreact.eu \t   https://cdn.jsdelivr.net \t   https://fonts.gstatic.com \t   https://themes.googleusercontent.com; \tconnect-src 'self' \t   https://*.amazonaws.com \t   https://*.analytics.google.com \t   https://*.googletagmanager.com \t   https://*.google-analytics.com \t   https://*.goreact.com \t   https://*.goreact.com:* \t   https://*.goreact.eu \t   https://api-iam.intercom.io \t   https://api.hubapi.com \t   https://api-standard.opentok.com \t   https://analytics.google.com \t   https://bam.nr-data.net \t   https://config.opentok.com \t   https://edge.fullstory.com \t   https://ekr.zdassets.com \t   https://forms.hubspot.com \t   https://goreact.zendesk.com \t   https://hlg.tokbox.com \t   https://px.ads.linkedin.com \t   https://rs.fullstory.com \t   https://speakworks.pubnub.com \t   https://stats.g.doubleclick.net \t   https://www.facebook.com \t   https://www.google.com \t   wss://*.ibm.com \t   wss://*.media.prod.tokbox.com; \tframe-src 'self' \t   https://*.googletagmanager.com \t   https://*.goreact.com \t   https://*.goreact.com:* \t   https://*.goreact.eu \t   https://*.youtube.com \t   https://td.doubleclick.net \t   https://www.facebook.com; \tobject-src 'none'; \treport-uri https://app.goreact.com/api/v2/csp-report;",
        "disposition": "report",
        "blocked-uri": "https://www.facebook.com/privacy_sandbox/pixel/register/trigger/?id=1226001014150573&ev=SubscribedButtonClick&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.goreact.com%2Fdashboard%2Fsessions%2F33788610&rl=&if=false&ts=1730131123374&cd[buttonFeatures]=%7B%22classList%22%3A%22btn%20btn-default%22%2C%22destination%22%3A%22%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22imageUrl%22%3A%22%22%2C%22innerText%22%3A%22Excellent%22%2C%22numChildButtons%22%3A0%2C%22tag%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%22%7D&cd[buttonText]=Excellent&cd[formFeatures]=%5B%5D&cd[pageFeatures]=%7B%22title%22%3A%22GoReact%20%7C%20Dashboard%20-%20ASL%20I-%20Period%206%22%7D&sw=1280&sh=720&ud[external_id]=36e4da20df0937f58a42fde32d66440e&v=2.9.174&r=stable&a=hubspot&ec=31&o=4126&fbp=fb.1.1728910231395.736716853676990415&ler=empty&cdl=API_unavailable&it=1730131053674&coo=false&es=automatic&tm=3&exp=i2&rqm=FGET",
        "status-code": 200,
        "script-sample": ""
    }
}

Notice that despite https://www.facebook.com being in the original-policy under img-src, it still triggers the error. I've searched to see if anyone else had this problem, but I could not find any other answers that weren't about blob, data, or missing semicolons. I've triple checked that the semicolons between the directives are correct. I thought it may be the tabs, but that didn't cause any issues as far as I could tell. I further went to the site, opened the developer console, and added an <img> tag directly with that uri and it didn't complain, so I can't seem to reproduce the issue, however we are still getting logs of it (275 in the last 2 hours)
Is there some special circumstance that the image would be blocked anyways, despite being allowed in the policy? Is there anything I can add to handle that case? The user's browser is Chrome 129 on Windows 10.
